# Need to multiply one XMM register by another, but with bit masked value

Tags: c, optimization, assembly, graphics

In x86/SIMD assembly, I've populated an XMM register with four 32 bit pixels of a graphic image I need to convert. However, the pixels are in 10 bit packed RGB format, so they exist in 32 bits in this form:

```
[  red   ][  green ][  blue  ][]
RRRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBBBB00
```

The last two bits are padding bits and are unused.

I need to multiply these pixels by another value, but the value needs to be masked so it only affects say, the red pixels. This value is constant, so it can be hard-coded. Let's say the value is 0.1234. How would I put this into another XMM register with appropriate masking so it only affects the red portion of each 32 bit segment?

Illustrated graphically, I would like to do something like this:

```
XMM0 (first 32 bit segment):
[ 0.1234 ][  1.0   ][  1.0   ][]

*

XMM1 (first 32 bit segment):
RRRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBBBB00
```

With the result being the product of XMM0 and XMM1. Of course, this 32 bit segment would be duplicated across the entire XMM register, I just specified the first 32 bits here so you get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you really only wanted to affect the red portion you might be able to come up with a trick that will multiply the red and part of the green by some constant (treating the register as a collection of 16-bit shorts) and then recombining just the new red part with the old green and blue.

A better strategy if you're going to operate on all of the colors is to unpack that format into a supported xmm register format (like 16- or 32-bit short or float) using a combination of shift and shuffle (and possibly convert to float) operations.  Then do all of your math, then pack it back.

If you are ever re-using any values (for example, if you are computing a filter kernel) and you're working in float, it will be much faster if you unpack and convert to float *once* and then re-use that value over and over.  Even if you have to make a loop that unpacks a whole row to 32-bit float before operating on it and re-packing the whole row.

Comment: Shuffle is no good, since the RGB values are packed into a single 32-bit coponent of an XMM register. Though I agree on the rest, doing a shift-and-multiply-shift-or(and) thingie is probably the best way (if there is a good way at all).

Comment: @Damon: I meant `PSHUFB` as a first pass to get all the R, G and B bits (shifted, surrounded by other bits that don't belong) into 16- or 32-bit alignment, then using masking and shifting.  Depending on what you're going to do you could `PSHUFB` as I described, `PAND` to mask off the unrelated bits, and then directly `CVTPI2PS`.  Due to shift, some of the values will be shifted (eg red always has 6 bits of green below, masked off, so it's 64.0*R) but you can bake the conversion into the multiply (i.e. `0.1234/64.0`) **or** leave it scaled that way for the re-packing.

Comment: Ah I see. Though that's probably still not something I'd do because it creates a dependency on SSSE3, which is not well-supported, for something that a simple shift probably does just as well (if I understood right, the OP only wants one channel, so that should be kind of trivial, shift by 22 in the case of R). On the other hand, if one wants all three channels, going `PSHIFB` might give a huge advantage, though.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use PSHUFB to unpack four pixels into two 16 bit per component pixels just using shifts and masks (from four pixels in XMM0 to two pixels in XMM1). However, it seems there is no way to actually perform any math on data arranged this way. Must I unpack each 32 bit element into its own XMM register? The idea would be to take one 32 bit packed RGB element and unpack it into 4x single precision floats. So, from say one "input" XMM register I now have four XMM registers which contain each pixel as 32 bit floats. I don't need 32 bits of precision but I don't see any other way.

Comment: Actually, I can get away with using only three additional registers since I don't need an alpha channel. RGB (3) * 4 pixels = 12.

Comment: @Synthetix: The 16-bit integer SSE instructions aren't as rich as the float instructions, but you could use `PMULHW` which multiplies 16-bit words and returns the upper 16 bits of the result.  So it's equivalent to `result = (a * b) >> 16`, so .1234 becomes 8087/65536.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to use floating point to multiply your values, I would unpack the R/G/B values into individual floating point sections of an XMM register (just divide by 1023.0) for each value.

You may also find that it's actually easier to prepare four R, four G, and four B values, and then build a value that has the same multiplier for each of the colour values in another XMM register, and multiply by that, rather than holding R, G and B in one register. Obviously, this would require a bit of unrolling of the loop, but that tends to improve performance quite a bit anyway.